# ASP reading Access database: "Requested operation requires a current record."

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ms-access

I have problem with this code I got  no error but the result is a blank a white output,please help why this is happen ,few days ago the code is working properly but after some day it results in blank output.
    i am hosted this code on the server that support older asp 2.0 and ms access 2003 having .mdb extension files

```
 <html>
    <body>
    <div id ="pin">
    <%

      city= Request.Form("username")
      area = Request.Form("password")

        Dim Conn,rs,strSQL

        Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
         Conn.Open"Provider= Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("/pinner/db/database1.mdb") 
        'Conn.Open"DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb);DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("/pinner/db/Database1.mdb")
        'strSQL = "SELECT pincodes.officename FROM pincodes where pincode = '" & city & "';"
        Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

        strSQL = "Select  pincode from pincodes  WHERE Districtname = '" city "' AND officename = '" area "';"
        'strSQL = "Select  pincode from pincodes  WHERE (Districtname  like "&city& *" AND officename like "&area&*");"
        rs.Open strSQL,Conn

        If (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
        Response.Write ("<br>")
        Response.Write ("[pincode] not found")
        Response.Write ("<br>")
        Else
        Response.Write ("<br>")
        Response.Write (rs("pincode"))
        Response.Write ("<br>")
        End If




    rs.close

     Set rs = Nothing
     Set Conn = Nothing

    %>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It appears that you query is not returning any records. After opening the recordset, check to see if EOF is true and if so then bypass the reference to rs("pincode").

Comment: Ok , i have resolved my problem every one get success my blessings

Comment: Database help still need for selective search

Comment: @rontornambe please check my code again

Answer (score 2):

Since you have no guarantee that the SELECT query will return any rows you'll have to test the `EOF` property of the recordset. In other words, you'll need to do something like this:

```vbs
' ...
rs.Open strSQL,Conn
If rs.EOF Then
    Response.Write ("<br>")
    Response.Write ("[pincode] not found")
    Response.Write ("<br>")
Else
    Response.Write ("<br>")
    Response.Write (rs("pincode"))
    Response.Write ("<br>")
End If
' ...
```

Comment: after running this code it shows error pincode not found

Comment: @satish then the recordset is not returning any records. Troubleshooting why would be a different question entirely.

Comment: @AnonJr after using above code that explain by gord it works but now i again try to retrieve value it shows blank result ,plus i also want answer about db query problem

Comment: @satish - You've [already asked that question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18804866/25163) and received an answer as best as can be provided with the question written as it is. If you're not getting an answer, improve your question. **Side Note:** you appear to have asked this a [couple of times](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18802976/25163), please don't post the same question again and again - edit and improve instead.

Comment: @AnonJr i have edited code please see and resolve query

Comment: @satish you've missed the point. You changed the question to the point that the answer doesn't make sense. Gord answered your original question. The new problem is a new question - which you already asked. Twice. You aren't getting answers on those because your question is poorly formed.

Comment: @AnonJr gord problem not resolve the code error need help

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more complete example of how to iterate through your records.  Hopefully this puts you on your way.

```
Sub TestIt
  Dim Conn
  Dim RST
  Dim dbError
  Dim dbCredDB
  Dim dbCredServer
  Dim dbCredUser
  Dim dbCredPass
  Dim queryString

  ' Set up Parameters
  dbCredDB = "TestDB"
  dbCredServer = "testserver"
  dbCredUser = "TestUser"
  dbCredPass = "TestPass"
  queryString = "SELECT 'Test' AS Test FROM DUAL"

  ' Open Connection
  Set Conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
' ** Oracle Connection Properties
  Conn.Provider = "OraOLEDB.Oracle"
  Conn.Properties("Data Source") = dbCredDB
  Conn.Properties("User ID") = dbCredUser
  Conn.Properties("Password") = dbCredPass
' ** SQL Server Connection Properties
  ' Conn.Provider = "SQLNCLI11"
  ' Conn.Properties("Server") = dbCredServer
  ' Conn.Properties("Database") = dbCredDB
  ' Conn.Properties("Uid") = dbCredUser
  ' Conn.Properties("Pwd") = dbCredPass
  Conn.Open

  ' Open Recordset
  Set RST = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  Set RST.ActiveConnection = Conn
  RST.CursorType = 0 'adOpenForwardOnly
  RST.Open queryString, Conn

  ' Trap for Server Errors
  Err.Clear
  On Error Resume Next

  ' Run through each Record in Recordset - write value
  Do Until RST.EOF
    Response.Write (RST.Fields("Test").value + "<br>")

    ' Check for error
    if err.Number <> 0 Then
      For Each dbError in Conn.Errors
        Response.Write ("Error! " + dbError.Description + "<br>")
      Next
      Exit Do
    End If

    ' Move to next record
    RST.MoveNext
  Loop

  ' Stop Trapping for Errors
  On Error Goto 0

  ' Close Recordset and Connection
  RST.Close
  Conn.Close

  ' Free up references
  set RST = Nothing
  set Conn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Microsoft has also published a number of articles on how to achieve this.

How To Page Through a Recordset from ASP
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/202125

Comment: ASP-Classic/VBScript doesn't support `On Error GoTo Label`, only VB proper and VBA. If this is running within Access, then you can do what is posted. If this is running on an ASP-Classic page (as tagged, and illustrated in the code), then you only have `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error GoTo 0` to work with. [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53f3k80h(v=vs.84).aspx) [2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/08/19/error-handling-in-vbscript-part-one.aspx)

Comment: Moved the error trapping to point of error.  Thanks for catching that.

Comment: @DHW where i put   Response.Write (rs("pincode")) and you use oraRSt what i use in place ora

Comment: Right you are.  I updated my answer to change "oraRST" to "rst".  Whether you use RST("Test") or RST.Fields("Test") makes no difference.