# Send search Pointer to start in MS access

Tags: sql, ms-access, asp-classic

My code is as follows before copying code here i have writing the problem, when i query some time it shows pincode as query in code mention and some time show not found and now today it is showing blank no result even no error on querying,i thought the problem is when i query the data the pointer is locate on the place of record where it is last  queried but not again flush the memory and go to start of database or in program, any one help me how to get rid off

code is in asp 
querying mS access mdb 2003

```
<html>
<body>
<div id ="pin">
<%

  city= Request.Form("username")
  area = Request.Form("password")

    Dim Conn,rs,strSQL

    Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
     Conn.Open"Provider= Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("/pinner/db/database1.mdb") 
    'Conn.Open"DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb);DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("/pinner/db/Database1.mdb")
    'strSQL = "SELECT pincodes.officename FROM pincodes where pincode = '" & city & "';"
    Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    strSQL = "Select  pincode from pincodes  WHERE Districtname = '" & city & "' AND officename = '" & area & "';"
    'strSQL = "Select  pincode from pincodes  WHERE (Districtname  like "&city& *" AND officename like "&area&*");"
    rs.Open strSQL,Conn

    If rs.EOF or rs.BOF Then
    Response.Write ("<br>")
    Response.Write ("[pincode] not found")
    Response.Write ("<br>")
    Else
    Response.Write ("<br>")
    Response.Write (rs("pincode"))
    Response.Write ("<br>")
    End If




rs.close
Conn.close
 Set rs = Nothing
 Set Conn = Nothing

%>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To move the recordset pointer to the first record:

```
rs.MoveFirst
```

To check to see if there are any records in the recordset you need to check to see if both EOF and BOF are true:

```
If (rs.EOF AND rs.BOF) Then
    Response.Write ("<br>")
    Response.Write ("[pincode] not found")
    Response.Write ("<br>")
Else
    Response.Write ("<br>")
    Response.Write (rs("pincode"))
    Response.Write ("<br>")
End If
```

It sounds to me like you probably still have a problem in your query that is preventing you from finding the record you want.

Comment: how to get out off this problem please help i am new in asp i am java person

Comment: any solution for this difficulty